# Does facebook login api use oauth or oauth 2 protocol?

Tags: facebook, meteor, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a stocktwits oauth 2 package for meteor which I will post to atmosphere when it is polished up. Before I set out on this journey, I am looking to use an existing meteor oauth2 package as my model. facebook and facebook-ui seem like good ones to use as my skeleton which I am browsing [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/). I notice that the facebook package has oauth2 as a dependency. So my main question is the following, is the existing facebook, accounts-facebook packages based in oauth2? Because this would serve as a great starting point for the stocktwits oauth integration I need to make.